# Electricity from hydro plant supplied by Ram pump?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Would it be possible to get continuous power from hydro electric plant supplied from reservoirs fed using ram pumps set inline. For example stream emerging from ground supplied first ram pump, (ram pumps discharge a small quantity of water when running) excess from ram pump runs back into stream. The pumped water is relayed by a series of ram pumps up to top reservoir feeding the power plant, run off from each of the higher pumps runs into similar reservoirs and is used to power yet more ram pumps which feed up the landscape to achieve better efficiency.
Hope my explanation is clear.Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2):

ram pumps, while simple and cheap, are inefficient. concatenating them as you describe would make the overall efficiency of your scheme quite low- most of the energy available would be dissipated before it has the chance to perform useful work for you. A better solution is as follows: the two determinants of optimum performance of a hydro power plant are 1) the distance available through which the water can fall (called the "head", measured in feet) and 2) the available quantity of water on hand which can flow through the system (expressed in cubic feet per second). for any given combination of head and available flow there is an optimum turbine design which can be selected from among the various designs available off-the-shelf. In this connection, look up "francis turbine" for a good example of the current state-of-the-art and the history of its development.